# Make stdin and stderr visible

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zsh

is there a way to make `stdin` and `stderr` visible in unix bash/zsh/whatever?

Maybe turn the stderr output to red or something like that.

It is always a pain if you are figuring out why you can't parse the output from command x. This often drives me crazy. Then I do the `2>` thing but at this point 30 minutes are already gone...

-Timo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution a tiny little dylib from github: https://github.com/sickill/stderred

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I usually just do

```
command | grep '.*'
```

I have set $GREP_COLORS to

```
ms=01;32:mc=01;32:sl=:cx=:fn=35:ln=32:bn=33:se=36
```

which means the stdout is green while stderr stays black (or white).

Comment: `grep '.*'` is unnecessarily greedy/slow : it will grep anything (empty or non empty) but will take more processing time as it tries to expand to the whole line, step by step. Instead use : `grep '^'` (which match anything, also empty lines) or `grep .` (which doesn't match empty lines)

Comment: @OlivierDulac: Have you tried it? `grep` only colours the matched string, therefore `^` does not colour anything.

Comment: Anyway, this looks like a dirty hack ;-). Isn't there a built-in feature?

Comment: @methanol: Not in the shell. There might be clients that do that, though (e.g. `shell` in `emacs`).

Comment: Ah! Then I ask my question wrong. I use Terminal.app so it should have a feature like that not the shell itself. hm?

Comment: @choroba: oops, sorry! I didn't thought about that. But maybe adding the anchors:  `grep '^.*$'` would help it to know it has to match the whole line and thus speed things up ? (not sure...). Sorry again :(.  +1 to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [stderred](https://github.com/sickill/stderred) to automagically colorize `stderr`. It's a shared library that intercepts certain stream functions, so works with any program that uses those functions to write to your terminal.